# Scroll a matrix with another matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix

I have the following matrix:

[image]

I have to pass through every position of the red matrix.For every element of the red matrix I have to move it's neighbours depending on the red matrix border size (green) in a vector.Until now i have the following code,but I don't think it's well done:

```
for(i=border ; i < width + border ; i++){
    for(j = border ; j < height + border ; j++){
        for(x = i - border ; x <= 2 * border + 1 ; x++){
            for(y = j - border ; y <= 2 * border + 1 ; y++){
                buffer[z] = blue_matrix[x][y];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cand anyone help me with an idea,plese?

Comment: have you tried running this code? are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you also provide an image with the end result of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If I understand what you've drawn, you're trying to move the green matrix around so that the cell marked with an X visits all the squares in the red matrix, and no cells of the green matrix ever move outside the blue matrix. Is that correct?

Comment: You should probably be using OOP for this - but I suspect that you're new to C / C++ so perhaps a pointless suggestion?

Comment: @BobJarvis: correct,with the mention:after  i read all the elements from the green matrix,I copy them to a vector then I sort the vector in an ascending order.After the sort is done, I take the middle element of it and switch with the first element of the red matrix (this is the case for the first element of the red matrix). user3728501: i'm a newbie..

Comment: Do you want just one continuous vector for the output, or do you want separate vectors for each green cell?

Comment: So you're doing median filtering

Comment: @beaker: one continuous vector that should act like a temp for my sorting algorithm

Comment: @user3728501: C is an OOP language? Can you point me at any explicit OOP-features in the standard?

Comment: I think it's time to move the chatty stuff to chat...

Answer (score 1):

To iterate though the green matrix elements, the inner loop should probably look differently.

```
for(x = i - border ; x <= i + border ; x++)
{
  for(y = j - border ; y <= j + border; y++)
  {
     // do something
  }
}
```

What are you trying to achieve with the inner matrix? If you are moving green matrix by offset (h,v), the function would look like:

```
for(x = i - border ; x <= i + border ; x++)
{
  for(y = j - border ; y <= j + border; y++)
  {
     blue_matrix[x + h][y + v] = blue_matrix[x][y];
  }
}
```

The method above has a drawback: it might not do what you expect if the source and destination matrixes are overlapping.

Also, it is not clear from the description, but if you have to perform the same operation fore *every* position within the valid range, you can manually compute an algorithm for a final state without unnecessary intermediate steps.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually use the top-left corner of the corner of the green cell as your `i` and `j` and then store the results into `i+border, j+border`. That allows you to use `x` and `y` as offsets from the start position:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < width - 2*border ; i++){
    for(j = border ; j < height - 2*border ; j++){
        for(x = 0 ; x <= 2*border ; x++){
            for(y = 0 ; y <= 2*border ; y++){
                buffer[x*border + y] = blue_matrix[i+x][j+y];
            }
        }
        // Find median of buffer and store results in 
        //     blue_matrix[i+border][j+border]
    }
}
```

Comment: @B.Parker If I've misunderstood your question, please clarify.